# Why can't I get the attribute of the clicked element with this JavaScript arrow function?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, arrow-functions

I am populating an HTML table with data "extracted" from an array of objects:

```js
let cars = [{
    licensee: '23456 NY',
    arrival: new Date(2020, 9, 16, 11, 34, 30),
    leave: new Date(),
    isParked: true
  },
  {
    licensee: '56456 NY',
    arrival: new Date(2020, 8, 24, 10, 33, 30),
    leave: new Date(2020, 8, 24, 13, 50, 35),
    isParked: false

  },
  {
    licensee: '56780 NY',
    arrival: new Date(2020, 5, 12, 20, 33, 30),
    leave: new Date(2020, 5, 12, 21, 33, 30),
    isParked: false
  }
];

const formatDate = (date) => {
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12;
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
  var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
  return date.getDate() + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getFullYear() + " " + strTime;
}

const secondsToHours = (d) => {
  d = Number(d);
  let h = Math.ceil(d / 3600);
  return h;
}

const makeBill = (car) => {
  let arrivedAt = new Date(car.arrival).getTime();
  let leftAt = new Date(car.leave).getTime();
  //duration in seconds
  let duration = (leftAt - arrivedAt) / 1000;
  let hoursBilled = secondsToHours(duration);
  let billValue = car.isParked ? "-" : 10 + (hoursBilled - 1) * 5 + " LEI";
  return billValue;
}

const renterTable = () => {
  // Show new on top
  cars.reverse();

  let results = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    results += `<tr>
          <td>${cars[i].licensee}</td>
          <td>${formatDate(cars[i].arrival)}</td>
          <td>${formatDate(cars[i].leave)}</td>
          <td class="text-center">${showStatus(cars[i])}</td>
          <td class="text-right">${makeBill(cars[i])}</td>
          <td class="text-right">
            <button data-row="${i}" onclick="changeStatus(e)" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Summary</button>
             </td>
      </tr>`;
  }
  document.querySelector("#parking tbody").innerHTML = results;
}

const showStatus = (car) => {
  return car.isParked ? "In" : "Out";
}

const changeStatus = (e) => {
  let car = cars[e.target.dataset.row];
  console.log(car);
}

renterTable();
```

```css
#parking th,
#parking td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table id="parking" class="table table-striped m-0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Registration plate</th>
        <th>Arrived</th>
        <th>Deaparted</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th class="text-right">Pay</th>
        <th class="text-right">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

This little function is intended to log the car corresponding to the **clicked** "Summary" button to the console:

```
const changeStatus = (e) => {
  let car = cars[e.target.dataset.row];
  console.log(car);
}
```

Yet, instead of the desired result, I get `Cannot read property 'target' of undefined"` .

Where is my mistake?

Comment: `onclick="changeStatus()"` - you're explicitly passing no arguments, so `e` is `undefined`. There are a few ways you could fix this but my strong recommendation is not to use inline `onclick` attributes but to use `addEventListener` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get undefined because you didn't passed the event object. change:

```
onclick="changeStatus()"
```

to:

```
onclick="changeStatus(event)"
```

Also note that using inline handlers is **not a good practice**. if you care about good practices, don't use inline event handlers. *Instead select the element in javascript and attach the click event listener to it*:

```
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')
btns.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener("click", e => {
  let car = cars[btn.dataset.row];
  console.log(car);
}));
```

Comment: Also possible to do `changeStatus(this)` which will pass the element itself and the handler can then be `el => { let car = cars[el.dataset.row]; console.log(car); }`

Comment: If I change the function to `changeStatus(e)` I get `e is not defined`. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @RazvanZamfir not `changeStatus(e)`. use: `changeStatus(event)`. (`event` is a keyword)

Comment: Urrgh, this may work but using the `event` global is horrible, and this on top of inline event handlers. To the OP: please go with @Quentin's answer, not this one, if you care about good coding practice.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> const changeStatus = (e) => {
>  let car = cars[e.target.dataset.row];
> ```

It says it can't read `target` of `undefined`.

Therefore, `e` is `undefined`.

So look to see where the function is called:

> ```
> onclick="changeStatus()"
> ```

You aren't passing any arguments, so `e` gets a default value of `undefined`.

---

Don't use intrinsic event attributes. They have a host of problems.

If you add an event handler with `addEventListener` then it will get an event object as the first argument.

```
const buttons = document.querySelector(".btn-success");
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", changeStatus);
}
```

---

Consider using [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) instead of binding an event handler to each button individually.

Answer (score 1):

first of all you must pass something to function:

```
onclick="changeStatus(this)"
```

your THIS means at this moment 'this element' (this is so much 'this' in this answer!).

That means that you don't have event.target, but element:

```
const changeStatus = (element) => {
  let car = cars[element.dataset.row];
  console.log(car);
}
```

working code at:

https://jsfiddle.net/jmz37261/

btw. better choice is addEventListener instead of onclick.

@edit:

maybe it's better to go with this solution (in this specified case):

```
<button data-row="${i}" onclick="changeStatus(${i})" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Summary</button>
```

and then:

```
const changeStatus = (row) => {
  let car = cars[row];
  console.log(car);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

the issue is in your button tag : try to replace `onclick="changeStatus()"` by `onclick="changeStatus"`

you should pass the reference of your function to the button, that's why the event (your variable `e`) is not set

Comment: The value of an `onclick` is a function *body*. Mentioning a variable (even that if variable contains a function) won't do *anything* with it.